# How do I assign SQL results to variables or into an array in ActionScript 3?

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, flash, datagrid

I'm building a Flash AIR application that will be a kiosk installation for accepting visitor comments, and then displaying previous visitor's comments back.  This needs to be highly graphically styled, so returning the query/SQL results back into a datagrid isn't a suitable end result.  The database is simply the local one created by the Flash application since this is a non-networked kiosk installation.

I've seen many comments talking about datagrids, and I've seen code that will display all the query results back as a single string - but I'm hoping to populate (without clicking on a datagrid) a series of dynamic text fields with the results of my query.

The Insert statement is working great:

```
function addData(): void
{
insertStmt = new SQLStatement();
insertStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
var sqlAdd: String = "";
sqlAdd += "INSERT INTO comments (firstName, lastName, homeTown, comment, avatarID, tagID) ";
sqlAdd += "VALUES ('" + inputFirstName + "', ";
sqlAdd += "'" + inputLastName + "', ";
sqlAdd += "'" + inputHomeTown + "', ";
sqlAdd += "'" + inputComment + "', ";
sqlAdd += inputAvatarID + ", ";
sqlAdd += inputTagID;
sqlAdd += ")";

insertStmt.text = sqlAdd;

insertStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, insertResult);
insertStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, insertError);

insertStmt.execute();
}
```

I'm also able to get my Select statement to work when I click a button:

```
function getData(event: MouseEvent): void
{
selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
var sql: String = "SELECT firstName, lastName, comment FROM comments";
selectStmt.text = sql;

selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, traceResult);
selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);

selectStmt.execute();
}
```

Where I'm getting completely stuck is extracting this information and either giving each thing a variable name so I can use it later, or at least put the data into a multidimensional array so I reference data with a syntax like

```
array[1][firstName]
```

This is the code I've got isn't quite working:

```
function selectResult(event: SQLEvent): void
{
selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);

var result: SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult();

// The results grid works so I know I'm getting the data back
resultsGrid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(result.data);

var resultsArray01: Array;
var newResultsRow: Array;

if (result != null)
{
    // Iterate through each entry
    for each(var entry: Object in result.data)
    {
        // Trace entry  -- this works when I test it
        trace(entry.firstName,entry.comment, entry.homeTown);

        // Add entries to array -- where I get into troubles
        // I get TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
        newResultsRow.push(entry.firstName, entry.comment, entry.homeTown);
        resultsArray01.push(newResultsRow);
    }

}
}
```

Sorry if this is longwinded.  I'm pretty new to AS3, but fairly good with SQL.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You declared your Arrays, but you didn't instantiate them! `var resultsArray01: Array  = [];
var newResultsRow: Array = [];`

Comment: Thank you, @Karmacon!  That did help a lot.  I used
`    var resultsArray01: Array = new Array(); var newResultsRow: Array = new Array();`

The next thing I need to figure out is how to get the loop working properly to give resultsArray01 and new row per loop.  newResultsRow  is taking entries, but I'm not sure about resultsArray01
I'll investigate nested loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a multidimensional Array for this. You don't even need to create a loop. You can just store the Results as is.

```
//Declare variable to store the data
var resultsArray:Array;

var result: SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult();
if (result != null)
{
    resultsArray = result.data;
}
```

Then you can just do this...

```
trace(resultsArray[1]["firstName"]);
```

Although it is better to use dot syntax

```
trace(resultsArray[1].firstName);
```

Comment: This works beautifully.  I'm not sure if I'm dumb or if there's not enough documentation, or both.  Thank you.   I'm just curious why it's better to use dot notation vs square brackets.

Comment: It's not better at all, using brackets is fine. In both question and answer, checking if result is not null will not prevent the code to break and is not a guaranty that data is actually present, result could be not null but still have no data present. The correct statement should be: if(result && result.data && result.data.length)

Comment: @BotMaster I was suggesting that dot notation is better as a general rule, in that it allows you to find errors at compile time, while brackets do not. Although in this situation it won't make a difference... And yes, you should be checking for null data

Comment: To rephrase, it won't make a difference if you are working with dynamic types, such as Object. But if you were to map your results into a model, it would give you the benefit of compile-time error checking. Therefore it is better imo

Comment: Thank you both for the extra comments.  @BotMaster - Even though this app will exist in a very controlled environment, I appreciate your help on making a more robust check on the if statement.  And again to Karmacon for helping me break through this seemingly simple roadblock I'd hit.

Comment: @Kristian You're welcome. If you're satisfied please mark the answer as correct